# Is it possible to change a shortcode within a page dynamically

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, swap, shortcode

I have added shortcode to 400 posts (social share), but when upgraded to the premium version the shortcode has changed slightly and now will not work...

Is there a way to swap out the shortcode for a different one dynamically, using possible SQL or JavaScript?

The shortcode has a CSS class attached to it.

SQL has been suggested but I am not sure how to go about it.

The website is using WordPress.

Comment: You should at least tell us which is the plugin and the two version required for the shortcode (paste the old one and the new one). Another question to choose which path (JS or SQL) to take is: what changed? For example if the shortcode name changed you can't use JS

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL query, go to PHP my admin > SQL

```
update wp_posts set post_content =
replace(post_content,'[Old Shortcode]','[new shortcode]');
```

Click on the ‘Go’ button to continue.

You also can use the [**Better Search Replace**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) plugin. I found this more convenient. With the plugin, you can easily replace any words/shortcodes. with new words/shortcodes.